# Derived type of generics C#

Tags: c#, class, generics, interface

I have the following code

```
interface IEncryption{}
class EncryptionA : IEncryption {}
class EncryptionHandler<T> where T: IEncryption{}
class EncryptionMenu
{
    public EncryptionMenu(EncryptionHandler<IEncryption> encryption){}
}

void main()
{
   EncryptionMenu encryptionMenu = new EncryptionMenu(new EncryptionHandler<EncryptionA>()); // Error
}
```

I get

> "Argument type 'EncryptionHandler< EncryptionA>' is not assignable to
>   parameter type 'EncryptionHandler< IEncryption>'"

and I cant understand why it cant convert it even though EncryptionA implements IEncryption and is supposed to cast it. I tried to make the EncryptionMenu generic too but it makes the same error bubble upwards and complicates the code.

Comment: Learn about covariance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark T as out:
   class EncryptionHandler where T: IEncryption{}

its about c# [co/contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Comment: Classes cannot be covariant.